# Change javascript onclick event to jquery click and still pass parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I think I may be missing something or haven't grasped a fundamental of jQuery. I have searched for hours but yet to find an answer to my question.

I've got an old website that I'm upgrading to use jQuery and many of the links call a JavaScript `onClick` call that passes multiple parameters, as per the example below:

```
<a href="#" onclick="displayData('Book Title', 'ISBN', 'dateOfPublishing', 'Price');">View Details</a>
```

The problem is that I've updated the old `displayData` function with various jQuery code and the `displayData` function is within the

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
});
```

code, and this seems to prevent the function `displayData` being called using the `onClick` as it says *object expected*. I've moved the `displayData` function out from the `$(document).ready()` but by doing so, this has prevented references to other functions within the `$(document).ready()` code being referenced.

A cut down example of what I have is below:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function displayData(title, isbn, dt, price) {
      // there's a call to jQuery AJAX here
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "WebServices/BookService.asmx/GetBookReviews",
            data: "{isbn: '" + isbn + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                DisplayReviews(msg.d);
            }
        });
      return false;
    }

    function DisplayReviews(data) {
       // data normally formatted here and passed to formattedData variable
       var formattedData = FormatData(data);
       $('#reviewScreen').html(formattedData);
    }

    function FormatData(data) {
      // function reformats data... code removed for space..
      return data;
    }


  });
</script>


<table>
  <tr><td><a href="#" class="reviewLink" onclick="displayData('Book Title', '1234141HABJA1', '2010-01-12', '$15.99');">View Reviews</a></td><td>Book Title</td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#" class="reviewLink" onclick="displayData('Book TItle 2', '516AHGN1515', '1999-05-08', '$25.00');">View Reviews</a></td><td>Book Title 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

What I'd like to do is to be able to remove the `onclick="displayData();"` within the link and instead us a jQuery click reference, something like

```
$('a.reviewLink').click(function() {
  displayData(parameters go here....);
});
```

I just don't know how I'd pass the parameters to the function from the link as they would not longer be in the HTML `onclick` attribute.

If I continue to use the `onclick` attribute in the link, and move the `displayData(params)` out of the `$(document).ready()` code block, it works fine, but the moment I try and reference any of the other functions within the `$(document).ready()` code block I get the dreaded *object expected* error with the other functions such as `DisplayReviews(param)`.

I don't know if this makes any sense.... sorry if it's confusing, I'm not the worlds best programmer and don't know all the terminology necessarily, so have tried as best I can to explain. I hope you can help.

Many thanks

Comment: can you modify the HTML or do you need to extract the parameters from the existing `onclick` attribute?

Comment: I can modify the HTML, I just wasn't sure whether to stick with the existing onclick or try and better utilize jQuery and extract the parameters some other way. The HTML is dynamically generated so the parameters necessary are appended at this time, hence why i used to used the onclick attribute. Thanks!

Comment: You could create the necessary JavaScript (namely attaching the click handler) also dynamically.

Comment: @Felix: I'll have a look at attaching the click handler dynamically, but do like the idea of the HTML5 BGerrissen refers to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The init code should go into the .ready(), not your library functions, those can be defined in a seperate .js file.

```
<script src="yourFunctions.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

         $('a.reviewLink').click(function() {
             displayData(parameters go here....); // in yourFunctions.js
         });

    });
</script>
```

An alternative to passing inline parameters without using inline javascript, is to use HTML5's 'data-' attribute on tags. You can use it in xhtml, html etc as well and it just works.

html:

```
<div data-name="Jack" data-lastname="black">My name is</div>
```

jquery:

```
 $('div').click(function(){
      alert($(this).attr('data-name') + ' ' + $(this).attr('data-lastname'));
 });
```

Note: You HAVE to use either jQuery's `.attr()` or native `.getAttribute()` method to retreive 'data-' values.

I use 'data-' myself all the time.

Comment: Hi BGerrissen, thanks. The only thing I'm not clear on is how I get the parameters. The HTML was dynamcially generated originally and that's why I used the onclick="displayData(params);" attribute, as I defined the param values into each link at runtime. I can see how the example above works, but I just can't see where the parameters to pass to displayData are coming from when I click on the link. Sorry to be thick! :-)

Comment: That's pretty cool! I guess it needs a different DocType... I'll have a search online for which one to use for HTML5, this sounds perfect!! :-)

Comment: Nah, you don't *need* a different doctype, only when html validation is important and even then chances are a lot of your html is invalid but actually valid...

Comment: Shifting the code around worked really well, and i've gone for the HTML5 data attributes. DocType seems to work for all browsers I've tested. It's even working with the old onclick="" attribute I had before!! Thanks!

Comment: @BGerrissen ...  in your comment you said that you have to use .attr() or .getAttribute().  I thought you could use jQuery's .data() as well. see jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: You can now, but you couldn't in 2010

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Skilldrick, `displayData` doesn't need to be defined inside your document ready wrapper (and probably shouldn't be).

You are correct in wanting to use the jQuery click event assignment rather than onClick - it makes your code easier to read, and is required by the principle of Unobtrusive Javascript.

As for those parameters that you want to pass, there are a few ways to go about the task.  If you are not concerned with XHTML compliance, you could simply put some custom attributes on your link and then access them from your script.  For example:

```
<a href="#" booktitle="Book Title" isbn="ISBN" pubdate="Publish Date" price="Price">View Details</a>
```

And then in your click event:

```
$('a.reviewLink').click(function() {
  var booktitle = $(this).attr('booktitle');
  var isbn = $(this).attr('isbn');
  var pubdate = $(this).attr('pubdate');
  var price = $(this).attr('price');
  displayData(booktitle, isbn, pubdate, price);
});
```

I'm sure someone on here will decry that method as the darkest evil, but it has worked well for me in the past.  Alternatively, you could follow each link with a hidden set of data, like so:

```
<a href="#">View Details</a>
<ul class="book-data">
   <li class="book-title">Book Title</li>
   <li class="book-isbn">ISBN</li>
   <li class="book-pubdate">Publish Date</li>
   <li class="book-price">Price</li>
</ul>
```

Create a CSS rule to hide the data list: `.book-data { display: none; }`, and then in your click event:

```
$('a.reviewLink').click(function() {
  var $bookData = $(this).next('.book-data');
  var booktitle = $bookData.children('.book-title').text();
  var isbn = $bookData.children('.book-isbn').text();
  var pubdate = $bookData.children('.book-pubdate').text();
  var price = $bookData.children('.book-price').text();
  displayData(booktitle, isbn, pubdate, price);
});
```

There are lots of ways to accomplish your task, but those are the two that spring most quickly to mind.

Comment: Thanks man, these are also useful ideas! I guess the HTML5 "data" attribute tags superseeds this, but really useful as an alternative. :-)

Comment: Yeah, those data attribute tags definitely solve the problem cleanly.  The only issue with using them would be if you need to support older browsers that don't support HTML5.  Then again, if you're supporting an older browser, XHTML compliance is probably a concern, so the normal custom attributes still wouldn't work...

Comment: @Ender: Yes, they do, even in IE6, see [Do HTML5 custom data attributes “work” in IE 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6)

Comment: @Marcel - Sorry, I was unclear there.  I didn't mean that it would break, just that custom attributes aren't XHTML compliant, using standard W3C validators.  Of course you could always define your own doctype, but that's a headache in itself.

Comment: Again, the answer to that problem is simply `<!DOCTYPE html>`; your headaches will vanish instantly, and much cheaper than paracetamol.

Comment: Have used the <!DOCTYPE html> as my chosen solution and it works on IE6+ and Chrome and Firefox 3, so looks like a great option. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I worked this up, so even though the question is answered, someone else might find it helpful.
http://jsbin.com/axidu3

HTML

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="reviewLink">View Reviews</a>
            <div class="displayData">
                <span class="title">Book Title 2</span>
                <span class="isbn">516AHGN1515</span>
                <span class="pubdata">1999-05-08</span>
                <span class="price">$25.00</span>
            </div>
            </td>
        <td>Book Title 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery(".reviewLink").click(function() {
        var title = jQuery(".title", this.parent).text();
        var isbn  = jQuery(".isbn", this.parent).text();
        var pubdata = jQuery(".pubdata", this.parent).text();
        var price = jQuery(".price", this.parent).text();

        displayData(title, isbn, pubdata, price);
    });

    function displayData(title, isbn, pubdata, price) {
        alert(title +" "+ isbn +" "+ pubdata +" "+ price);
    }
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .displayData {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This is definitely a neat solution if not using the HTML5 data attributes. Thanks for such a clean example Sandro.