# Is there any problem with using HTML5's "data-*" attributes for older browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, custom-data-attribute

I want to associate some custom data with some HTML nodes. I was going to use the new HTML5 style 'data-*' attributes. e.g.: `<tr class="foo" data-typeid="7">…`, and then I was going to select this HTML node and show/hide it etc. by reading the value with `$(node).attr("data-typeid")`.

However this web page needs to work with older browsers aswell. I'm not using the data-* attribute as a special attribute, but I'd like to know if older browsers will ignore, wipe, or make inaccessible this attribute since it's not valid HTML4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do HTML5 custom data attributes “work” in IE 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There isn't really, they're not 100% correct/valid usage in HTML4 of course....*but they don't cause problems either*, so they're still a great way to solve the "I need an attribute for this" problem.

If it helps, I've used these while supporting IE6 and have had zero issues thus far, and I can't recall a single SO question reporting any either.

Comment: HTML5 was designed to work as far as possible with existing browser behaviour. Data attributes are one of the nice places, like the HTML5 doctype, where that seems to happen without many hiccups.

Comment: It seems that you can't use data types with jquery using the XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype with IE 8 and below.

Answer (score 11):

Internet Explorer and Microsoft has added several custom attributes that are not valid HTML4. Browsers don't check the element attributes against a specification, you can name an attribute `roryscoolinfo="hello"` if you like (though you shouldn't).

The Dojo Toolkit adds its custom `dojo*` attributes.

It's fine to use `data-` today, with a HTML5 doctype.