# Server-side and AJAX and data manipulation

Tags: ajax, jquery, coldfusion, frontend

I'd like to get a census on methods of removing/adding records via AJAX and updating the front-end.

For tabular data (take an inbox for example):

[image]

When I want to remove that first message, where/how should I be referencing the ID of that message and sending it to my AJAX call? I've seen some people put the ID in a hidden field, or use the checkbox id attribute...

How is this transaction properly handled so that when my call is successful, I can "remove" that row with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I typically use to "attach" data like this to HTML elements is to use the [HTML5 `data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attribute.  This will allow you to store multiple pieces of data for use w/ Javascript/jQuery/Ajax, without doing anything "hacky" like embedding stuff in IDs or having to parse out values.

For example, in your case of a table row, you could have something like this:

```
<tr data-email-id="123"><td>...</td></tr>
```

Then it would be simple to reference in your jQuery (assume `$(this)` references the `tr`):

```
var emailId = $(this).attr('data-email-id');
```

Comment: So you're suggesting just making up an attribute, correct? I believe I've done this before... and from what I understand, jQuery doesn't care and it doesn't effect the integrity of the page.

Comment: I don't believe the browser cares that you're using HTML5, since this use of HTML5 isn't actually functional -- it's just a means of embedding data.  In other words, it won't break anything.  It just won't be considered "standards compliant" with that browser.

Comment: Quick follow-up, check out [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957867/is-there-any-problem-with-using-html5s-data-attributes-for-older-browsers/3957879#3957879) that answers your question re: HTML5 `data` attribute in older browsers (basically says the same thing I just said).

Comment: Yeah, this is the clarification I needed: "Internet Explorer and Microsoft has added several custom attributes that are not valid HTML4." - This is very true. I mean, you could create an attribute called "bostonbruinssuck=1" and it will work. Thanks a lot, Jerad!