# can I add an arbitrary attribute to a tag like <input type="text" preference="silly"/> and access it in JS code later

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a way to supplement a DOM element with extraneous attributes, or are the tags fixed with certain attribute by design?  As an example, is this possible?

```
<input id="spec" type="text" preference="silly"/>
```

And later access this element with jQuery or DOM requests like

```
if ($("#spec").attr("preference")=="silly") {
     document.write("That input is silly")
}
```

David

Comment: Yes, totally possible. Did you not try it?

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432174/how-to-store-arbitrary-data-for-some-html-tags

Comment: You can have your own elements, and browsers will just skip over them, as long as the attribute is nothing that it already understands, such as src for image tags or name.

Comment: It did not work for me, but maybe HTML has to be 5 and that is why?
Is there a way to create new attributes in jQuery code?

Comment: Your code as-is works after syntax errors are fixed. Your if statement is missing `(` and `)`

Comment: Thank you for the syntax, I wrote that on the fly in the question.  Corrected and still not working.  I have a fiddle if you want to take a look?  http://jsfiddle.net/balamba/hCFK2/23/

Comment: I got it to work, but not with the jQuery reference in the if statement.  Here is how... `u = jQuery('#spec').attr('preference');
if (u == 'silly') {`  Go figure!  I don't know why?

Comment: @Kevin B thank you for the help...  I got it going.  I guess it was just fiddle.  I have to get used to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding arbitrary extra attributes, at best, makes HTML invalid and risks conflicts with future changes to the language.

HTML 5 introduces [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) for storing arbitrary data in the DOM.

jQuery can access them via the [`data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

```
<input id="spec" data-preference="silly">
if (jQuery('#spec').data('preference') === 'silly') { ... }
```

Comment: What about the lower HTML like 4?

Comment: Earlier versions of HTML make no provision for anything like this.

Comment: I guess I have to post using people's names, for propagation reasons.  So, this is a formal thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply using [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
<input id="spec" type="text" data-preference="silly"/> 

if ($("#spec").data("preference") == "silly") {
     alert("That input is silly");
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957867/is-there-any-problem-with-using-html5s-data-attributes-for-older-browsers)

Comment: Very appropriate heads up, Will.  It ansewred many questions.  Thank you much...  DKoss