# addClass not working in IE8

Tags: jquery

It seems `addClass` is not working with IE8 for some reaosn. I made a `<div>` and a `<p>` , and I want to assign a class to `<p>` when the `<div>` is clicked but it is not working in IE8.

```
.test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

<div class="test"></div>

<p>deeded</p>

$('.test').click(function() {
    $('p').addClass('code');
});
```

The class does not get added in IE8. Why?

Comment: Which version of JQuery are using? JQuery 2.x doesn't support IE 6,7,8. As the [docs](http://jquery.com/download/) says - `jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.`.

Comment: the above would work even with jquery 2.x provided that `code` class is defined. Of course jquery 2.x does not attemp to fully support old IEs

Comment: Vucko, today i have learned a new thing. THANKS for the tip with ie8 and jquery 2. I replaced that with jQuery v1.12.4 and all my issues with addclass are gone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't define the `code` class and as you write in your comment (you should write that in your question..) you want to use the class as a *flag*

For this purpose you should use the HTML data attribute:

see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

and: [Is there any problem with using HTML5's "data-*" attributes for older browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957867/is-there-any-problem-with-using-html5s-data-attributes-for-older-browsers)

as you're interested in supporting IE8

Comment: No i did not define it. So there is no way to work if it is not defined? Becuase I need it as a flag only, not for styling

Comment: See the edit in my answer...

Comment: How does this answer the question? I understand this is a _different_ way of doing it but it doesn't address why `addClass` isn't working.

Comment: @Jonannes `addClass` is not working because the OP didn't defined the CSS class he's trying to add. I thought it was clear from the first sentence.