# How to linked or making related two different contents

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code snippet:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.show', function() {
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $('show').removeClass('open');

  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('open');

  if ($('#first').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#first-child').show();
  } else {
    $('#first-child').hide();
  };

  if ($('#second').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#second-child').show();
  } else {
    $('#second-child').hide();
  };

  if ($('#third').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#third-child').show();
  } else {
    $('#third-child').hide();
  };

});

$('body').on('click', '.show.open', function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
  $(this).removeClass('open');
  $(".child").hide();

});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: upper-alpha;
}

.show {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent">
  <li id="first">
    <div>Many Contents</div>
    <div class="show">Some More Clickable Contents</div>
  </li>
  <li id="second">
    <div>Many Contents</div>
    <div class="show">Some More Clickable Contents</div>
  </li>
  <li id="third">
    <div>Many Contents</div>
    <div class="show">Some More Clickable Contents</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="first-child" class="child">
  A's Related Contents
</div>
<div id="second-child" class="child">
  B's Related Contents
</div>
<div id="third-child" class="child">
  C's Related Contents
</div>
```

If you click on the "Some More Clickable Contents", related contents will be visible which are not actually Child content. So, I've to make this functionality like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.show', function() {  
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   if($('#first').hasClass('active')) {
      $('#first-child').show();
   } else {
      $('#first-child').hide();
   };
});
```

But, if I could add `href` at parent `li` with related content's `Id`, I will able to manage functionality with more small jQuery code like this:

```
<li id="first" href="#first-child"></li>

$('body').on('click', '.show', function() {  
   childId = $(this).parent().href
   childId.show();
});
```

So that, I need not check `if else` every time. But, `href` at `li` might not be allowed by W3c Validation. So, how can I linked those different contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data attributes

```
<li id="first" data-id="first-child"></li>
```

and javascript

```
$('body').on('click', '.show', function() {  
   childId = $(this).parent().data('id')
   $('#' + childId).show();
});
```

**UPDATE**

You skip dot at your show class

```
$('.show').removeClass('open');
```

Comment: @user1896653 answer you can find here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957867/is-there-any-problem-with-using-html5s-data-attributes-for-older-browsers

Comment: anyway you can work with classes with some prefix. this method should work in any browsers

Comment: Thanks! Can you please help me for one thing. Actually, I am not expert at jQuery. That's why, I can't understand why it's happened. The problem is:
If you click on the A. "Some More Clickable Contents", then B. "Some More...", then C. "Some More..." and then again A. "Some More..." A's related content isn't showing for first click, It's showing with double click!

Comment: @user1896653 What is your problem?

Comment: Hey! Ignore it. I've found the reason. I missed the '.' for show class at this line: $('show').removeClass('open'); 
Thanks for your help.