# Does element.attributes contain custom data-attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, custom-data-attribute

I was wondering if there is browser consistency what elements are stored in the attributes array.

Is all "data-xxx" attributes found through "$('#elm')[0].attributes"?

For example does the attributes-collection contain all the data-attributes below:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Go" data-validation="foo" data-widgetId="bar">
```

What I need is a way of moving all relevant attributes from an input[type=submit] to a button-element with jQuery.

Comment: must read this : http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Yeah .attr() rocks but it doesn't give me a object with key/value pairs to loop through.

Comment: i update your question.see the **edit** part..if it is not what u want then delete .

Comment: it was not what I meant, so yes I deleted it :)

Comment: You've got some answers to check

Answer (score 1):

I think the data attributes are present in all browsers even if they are ignored in the case of non HTML 5 browsers

Here someone managed to read them from an element in IE6 [Do HTML5 custom data attributes “work” in IE 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6)

@edited answer

just found that jquery data() works with both html5 and non html5 browers;

http://www.sluniverse.com/ffn/index.php/2011/02/using-html5s-data-attributes-with-jquery/

```
example of looping through all data attributes;

<input type="text" id="x" data-a="valuea", data-b="valueb" />
$.each($('#x').data(), function(key, value) { 
  console.log('key is', key);
  console.log('value is', value);
});            

prints         

key is a
value is valuea
key is b
value is valueb
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser support information regarding .attributes [HERE](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/attributes)

```
    var attrs = $("input[type=submit]")[0].attributes;
    for(var i=0;i<attrs.length;i++) {
        alert(attrs[i].nodeName + " = " + attrs[i].nodeValue);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. Yes I could test it like this in every browser I could imagine but I asked this question to see if anyone had already done that. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not many browsers currently have native support for the `dataset` property, which is the offical standard way to access `data-*` attributes. This will improve over time, but for now it's not well enough supported to use (see http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset for more).

However as you know all browsers can support `data-*` as normal attributes. But in the absence of the `dataset` property, there isn't an easy way to grab all the `data-*` attributes.

Fortunately, there is a JQuery plugin which provides this functionality. See here for more info: http://www.orangesoda.net/jquery.dataset.html