# Identify specific element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, css-selectors

I'm implementing a vote system and I want to use jQuery. I have the working  code for the vote on a single page, but the problem is that I want to be able to vote from my main page as well and I don't know how to identify for which post the vote is intended.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<p>
post content
<span><a href="#" class="voteUp">I approve this message <span>${post.upvotes}</span></a></span>
</p>

<p>
post #2 content
<span><a href="#" class="voteUp">I approve this message <span>${post.upvotes}</span></a></span>
</p>
```

(please ignore the multiple span tags)

This is the JS code I have right now:

```
$(".voteUp").click(function(){
    $.post(voteAction({postid: '5', type: 'up'}), function(data){
        $("")
    });
});
```

So how do I identify for which post the click is meant (and replace the hardcoded postid with the chosen id?) I could add the postid with `${post.id}` somewhere in the html, but I don't see how to exactly use it. I can't afford to generate a custom jQuery .click function for each post, right?

**EDIT:**

Any idea how I update the span tags content afterwards? I tried this but it's not working:

```
$.post(voteAction({postid: this.id, type: 'up'}), function(data){
    $(".voteUp a span").html(data);
});
```

Comment: what is `voteAction`? and `$.post` needs the url as the 1st parameter

Comment: Could you not give the <p> elements an ID? E.g. <p id="12321"> and use jQuery to get the id of parent element that is of type <p>? You will need to have your postid(s) somewhere.

Comment: @Colin: problem was I didn't know how to select the id once I add it to the p element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an id attribute to each link element:

```
<p>
post content
<span><a href="#" class="voteUp" id="1">I approve this message <span>${post.upvotes}</span></a></span>
</p>

<p>
post #2 content
<span><a href="#" class="voteUp" id="2">I approve this message <span>${post.upvotes}</span></a></span>
</p>
```

reference the element in the JS code:

```
$(".voteUp").click(function(){
    $.post(voteAction({postid: this.id, type: 'up'}), function(data){
        $("")
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm going with this one, seems like the easiest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `postid` somewhere in your template. It doesn't matter where as long as you can retrieve it every time.

Example:

```
<p>
post #2 content
<span><a href="#" class="voteUp" rel="${post.id}">I approve this message <span>${post.upvotes}</span></a></span>
</p>

$(".voteUp").click(function(){
    $.post(voteAction({postid: $(this).attr('rel'), type: 'up'}), function(data){
        $("")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the postid on the element using an `data-` attribute, e.g.

```
<p data-postid="5">
    <a href="#" class="voteUp">
</p>
```

Then on your click event:

```
$(".voteUp").click(function(){
    var $postBlock = $(this).closest("p"); // gets the post block

    var postid = $postBlock.data("postid"); // 5

    ...
}
```

Comment: But why `data-postid`, it breaks standards compliance.

Comment: No it doesn't, it is valid HTML 5: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ The question I have  is how well this is handled in all the different browsers.

Comment: @roberkules @Daff It works even on IE6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6/2413263#2413263

Comment: But is everybody doing now only HTML5? And yes, IE6 supports it - just saying it breaks standards compliance (a validator check will throw an error)

Answer (score 0):

you could store the id in the surrounding p tag

```
<p id="post-234">

</p>
```

and extract it from there using e.g. jQuery

```
$(this).closest("p").attr("id").split("-")[1] --> the ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the wrapper of the post along with a specific class ie.

```
<div class="post-votable" id="post-5">
<p>
post content
<span><a href="#" class="voteUp">I approve this message <span>${post.upvotes}</span></a></span>
</p>
```

then

```
$(".voteUp").click(function(){
    $.post(voteAction({postid: $('this').closest('.post-votable')[0].id.split('-')[1], type: 'up'}), function(data){
        $("")
    });
});
```

Comment: missing `'-'` inside your `split()`

Answer (score 0):

Give each link an ID that matchs the post ID, and then use

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

For the post ID

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to investigate using html5 data attributes.

For instance, your html may become:

```
<a href="#" class="voteUp" data-post-id="5">I approve....</a>
```

While your JS would read:

```js
$(".voteUp").click(function(){
    $.post(voteAction({postid: $(this).data("post-id"), type: 'up'}), function(data){
        $("")
    });
});
```

While this isn't the best doc available, this should