# Does Firefox 3 support Rails3 UJS, despite not supporting HTML5 data-* attributes?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, html, firefox-3, custom-data-attribute

Am I missing something or is Rails3 UJS incompatible with Firefox 3?

AFAIK, all the previous-gen browsers didn't support the HTML5 `data-` attributes, so does this mean all the Rails3-style UJS code won't work on Firefox browsers prior to Firefox 4? Are there workarounds if so?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can code your own alternative to the HTML5 `data-` attributes API (see [Do HTML5 custom data attributes “work” in IE 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6)), because HTML5 was designed to work with existing browsers as far as possible.

I’m entirely unfamiliar with Rails, but whatever Rails3 UJS is, it may well have its own built-in alternative to native HTML5 `data-` attribute support.

Comment: Thanks for linking that thread. looks to me like you can get the attributes in JS whether they're fully supported by the browser or not, I need to do a little more digging in to the new Unobtrusive JavaScript features in Rails3 to find out if that's all they require. Thanks Paul.

Comment: @NYCorey: you’re most welcome, and yup, that’s my understanding too. Best of luck!