# IE9 Javascript Undefined Variables

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following in my code, which has worked fine in IE 7 and 8, but it no longer works in IE 9 (unless the user runs in compatibility mode of course...)

```
<asp:Label ID="invNumLink" runat="server" Font-Underline="true" ForeColor="Blue" Text='<%# Eval("Order_No") %>' createDate='<%# string.Format(Eval("create_date").ToString(),"MM/dd/yyyy") %>'
                                operatorNo='<%# Eval("operator_no") %>' orderNo='<%# Eval("Order_No") %>' loc='<%# Eval("Location") %>' table='<%# Eval("table_no") %>' recall='<%# Eval("recall_code") %>'
                                orderID='<%# Eval("ID") %>' acrID='<%# Eval("ACR_ID") %>'
                                onclick="goToDetail(this.orderNo,this.createDate, this.operatorNo, this.loc, this.table, this.recall, this.orderID, this.acrID);" style="cursor:pointer" ></asp:Label>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToDetail(orderNo, createDate, operatorNo, loc, table, recall, orderID, acrID) {
        var URL = 'OrderDetailView.aspx?orderNo=' + orderNo + '&' + 'createDate=' + createDate + '&' + 'operatorNo=' + operatorNo + '&' + 'loc=' + loc + '&' + 'table=' + 
                                        table + '&' + 'recall=' + recall + '&' + 'id=' + orderID + '&' + 'acrID=' + acrID;
        day = new Date();
        id = day.getTime();
        window.open(URL, id, 'toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=1100,height=700,left = 62,top = 15')
    }
</script>
```

In IE9 all of the values sent to the "goToDetail" function are undefined.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

**EDIT**

I resolved this by adding the call to javascript from the code behind:

```
invNumLink.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("goToDetail('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}'); return false;", item.GetDataKeyValue("Order_No").ToString(),
                string.Format(item.GetDataKeyValue("Create_Date").ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy"),item.GetDataKeyValue("Operator_No").ToString(), item.GetDataKeyValue("Location").ToString(), 
                item.GetDataKeyValue("table_no").ToString(), item.GetDataKeyValue("recall_code").ToString(), item.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString(),item.GetDataKeyValue("ACR_ID").ToStrin
```

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: Did you try move the javascript block before your <asp:label> tag?

Comment: That won't help - the problem is that IE9 won't hand over the attribute values for non-standard attributes like the older browsers would.

Comment: @Pointy--that's totally not cool.... :(

Comment: @Aaron: More like it being totally not cool that it's taken 9 versions for Microsoft to make a browser that even attempts to be standards-compliant.

Comment: @Marc: But I'm so used to it!  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use data-attributes, which work like this:

Instead of:

```
<span operatorNo="value">
```

You use

```
<span data-operatorNo="value">
```

And access it with

```
this.getAttribute("data-operatorNo")
```

This works in IE6 and is documented as working in IE7+. [Do HTML5 custom data attributes “work” in IE 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is UGLY... but maybe passing in the values directly would solve your issue.

```
<asp:Label ID="invNumLink" runat="server" Font-Underline="true" ForeColor="Blue" Text='<%# Eval("Order_No") %>' createDate='<%# string.Format(Eval("create_date").ToString(),"MM/dd/yyyy") %>'
                                operatorNo='<%# Eval("operator_no") %>' orderNo='<%# Eval("Order_No") %>' loc='<%# Eval("Location") %>' table='<%# Eval("table_no") %>' recall='<%# Eval("recall_code") %>'
                                orderID='<%# Eval("ID") %>' acrID='<%# Eval("ACR_ID") %>'
                                onclick="goToDetail('<%# Eval("Order_No") %>','<%# string.Format(Eval("create_date").ToString(),"MM/dd/yyyy") %>', '<%# Eval("operator_no") %>', '<%# Eval("Location") %>', '<%# Eval("table_no") %>','<%# Eval("recall_code") %>', '<%# Eval("ID") %>', '<%# Eval("ACR_ID") %>');" style="cursor:pointer" ></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Won't work with the double quotes inside of the Eval statement, which I now remember is why I did it the way I did it before.  I think I'm going to have to add a style in the code behind...

Answer (score 1):

For non-standard attributes on an HTML tag, I believe you need to use `element.getAttribute("attName")` to fetch non-standard attributes defined in the HTML rather than directly access them with `element.attName`.  To stay with standards, you should also prefix custom data attributes with "data-".