# jQuery get by class and attribute

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a select like:

```
<select id="item_OfficeUserId" class="dropdownauditor" name="item.OfficeUserId" invoicelineid="33">
```

In jQuery I can get it by its class:

```
$(".dropdownauditor")
```

Is there a way to get it based on its class and it attribute invoicelineid="33" as well?

There will be more than one with `class="dropdownauditor"`. I want to get the selected item of the particular `select`. I was using:

```
$(".dropdownauditor").change(function () {
    $(".dropdownauditor option:selected").each(function () {
    ...
    }
}
```

But this is running through the second part twice. ie. It tis then finding the selected for every `select` with `class="dropdownauditor"` Is is possible to only find only one with `invoicelineid="33"`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
$(".dropdownauditor[invoicelineid='33']")
```

Using the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: Works in all browsers. I was told that syntax i s browser dependent.

Comment: @AnonyMouse: Hmm, I think you're okay. However, using arbitrary attributes is not recommended especially with `data-*` attributes around.

Comment: I'm new to those. Does that mean to just add data-* like data-invoicelineid?

Comment: @AnonyMouse: Yep! They are HTML5 but *shouldn't* cause problems in older browsers. Here's a good question on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6#