# Is there any possible negative repercussions of using made up attributes in html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coding-style

So suppose I have this tag

```
<a href=""></a>
```

and then I make up some non-standard attribute

```
<a lol="haha" href=""></a>
```

If you ask why, well so that I can conveniently use that made up attribute in my javascript...

My question is...is there any possible negative repercussion of doing this....is there any good reason why I shouldn't be doing this?

Comment: like others have said, add the "data-" prefix to your custom attributes. Like data-lol instead of just lol. According to the HTML5 spec, any custom attribute with that prefix is valid, others are not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browsers will almost universally handle custom attributes.  And when I say universally, I mean [even IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6).

Of course the standard way to do that is with:

```
<a data-lol="haha" href=""></a>
```

Which, since you've tagged with jQuery, I'll mention can be read (even in IE6) with

```
$("a").data("lol");
```

Comment: IE6 definitely handles it. IE5.5 handled it too. I can't remember further back than that. (Actually although I suspect it would've been fine I'm not sure if IE5.5 handled hyphenated attributes, but it _definitely_ handled one-word custom attributes like in the question.)

Comment: I was forced to use IE6 (and code for it) as recently as eighteen months ago, and really the main issues were more about non-standard handling (or lack of support) for certain CSS features. (The event-related stuff was easy enough to work around in most cases.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the HTML data- attribute [HTML 5 data- Attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Answer (score 1):

There is an attribute family that was made exactly for that: `data-*`. You should use

```
<a data-lol="haha" href="#"></a>
```

That will be valid and save you from any headaches. A custom attribute might conflict with a predefined one (or one that doesn't exist yet), or cause problems in non-compliant parsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with HTML5:

```
<a data-lol="haha" href=""></a>
```

As for the downsides, I will say this: standards are made for a reason. Just because it *looks* like it works won't mean that it *will* work in the future.

Comment: Note that even (at least some) pre-HTML5 browsers support this, so this is a pretty safe option.