# Changing link color programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, dynamic

I am currently changing styling from code behind by doing:

`Div.Style["StyleAttribute"] = MyValue;`

I want to change essentially only the `a` link tags color within the `Div` programatically is this possible?

The solution must not make use of HTML5.

The content is always dynamic, the links aren't static so using `runat="server"` is not possible.

Next step would be to see if I can change the **active**, **hover** and **visited** states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery version:

```
$('a', $('#divId')).css('color', 'red')
```

JQuery docs:

- [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)
- JQuery [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: Nice, but since I am getting the values that will be set from code behind anyway makes sense setting it their. If there isn't a solution. I may implement this would need to pass values from code behind to jquery which should be doable. +1 for fast response.

Comment: `$('a', $('.ContentRegion')).css('color', <%# Red %>);` I ended up doing this in code behind thanks to @gdoron

Answer (score 2):

If you choose this solution the page won't validate anymore, but it works across all browsers and does the job.

in your html you do:

```
<div class="StyledLinkWrapper">
    <style id="stylemylinks" runat="server"> </style>
    <a href="http://www.xyz.com">a Link</a>
</div>
```

and in the code behind simply:

```
 string colorNormal = "blue";
 string colorVisited = "red";
 string colorHover = "white";
 string bghover = "blue";
 StringBuilder style = new StringBuilder();
 style.AppendLine(".StyledLinkWrapper a {");
 style.AppendLine(String.Format(" color: {0};", colorNormal));
 style.AppendLine("}");
 style.AppendLine(".StyledLinkWrapper a:hover {");
 style.AppendLine(String.Format(" color: {0};", colorHover));
 style.AppendLine(String.Format(" background-color: {0};", bghover));
 style.AppendLine("}");
 style.AppendLine(".StyledLinkWrapper a:visited {");
 style.AppendLine(String.Format(" color: {0};", colorVisited));
 style.AppendLine("}");
 stylemylinks.InnerText = style.ToString();
```

and there you go. Just plain old Css, no fancy Javascript framework or whatever, and you are totally flexible in what  you can do.

Comment: great!

If it would be more widely supported (or at least a bit supported), I would go for the `scoped`attribute on the style element.. see http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/
But at the moment it's pointless...

Except if oyu want to use https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Try using data-attributes:

```
Div.Attributes.Add("data-link-color", "red");
```

jQuery:

```
$("#divID a").css("color", $("#divID").data("link-color"));
```

And you'll probably be able to use something similar for hover etc.

Comment: `data-attributes` would be a nicety but I have to support browsers not supporting HTML5.

Comment: While older versions of IE will not recognize the data-attributes, they won't break anything, and jQuery will indeed recognize them. (Simply by fetching all attributes beginning with "data-"), so it shouldn't be a problem. Further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6

Comment: Naturally they would - anything else would defeat the whole purpose. Whilst older browser won't know what to do with data-attributes, or implement any HTML5-specific functionality, all data in them can be accessed with JavaScript, at least as far back as IE6.

Answer (score 1):

use javascript/jquery

```
$("a:active").css("color", "red"); 
$("a:hover").css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

in html

```
<div runat="server" id="divControl">...</div>
```

in .cs file

```
protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divControl;
divControl.Styles.Add("height", number / anotherNumer);
```

you can apply styles.

hope this helps !!!

Comment: That won't be applied to `<a>` only.

Comment: Yeah I am essentially already doing this, this will apply values to everything within `divControl` I want to target `<a>` within `divControl`.

Comment: ok.. then i will provide still more simple solution, make that anchor tag runat='server' 

 <a href="#" id="anchor" runat="server">hello</a>

and .cs file 

anchor.Style.Add("height","200px");

Comment: I should of specified the content is dynamic, if it was static I would be able to specify the `runat="server"` tag on the links.