# Accessing data tag from a non HTML5 browser

Tags: jquery, html

I'm a total noob in the web arena, I've been learning jQuery lately. My concern is, will I be able to access the '**data**' attribute using jQuery from my HTML if my browser does not support HTML5?

Comment: As far as i am concerned you can use the data attribute of html 5 in any browser, I know that even Internet Explorer should have now issue, because IE ignores all the attributes it does not know how to render or use. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use the data attribute and you will be able to access it with jQuery even if the browser doesn't support HTML5:

```
var value = $('#foo').data('value');
```

where you have:

```
<div id="foo" data-value="bar">Baz</div>
```

The only thing is that the `data` attribute is not valid if your DOCTYPE is not HTML5 => if you try to use it in HTML 4.01 Transitional for example the validator will cry but your site will work without issues.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.attr` to access it like:

```
$(your_selector).attr('data-foo');
```

Comment: Could, but should not, especially when manipulating the data rather than reading them. With `attr()`, the data goes back into the DOM. With `data()`, it is kept separately. If you change a value with `attr()`, then read it with `data()` you will get different values. Also `attr()` deals with strings only, `data()` will convert to native types, like integers. Whatever you do, don't mix use of `attr()` and `data()` unless you really know what you're doing. My rule of thumb is to use `attr()` for reading original DOM metadata or changing DOM properties and using `data()` for application state.

Answer (score 1):

yes.
but if your browser does not suport HTML5, the `data`-attribute is not valid (X)HTML. However, this should not be a problem for accessing the data with jQuery.