# How to change a javascript function's parameter from callback function

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML input element generated by the server and it looks like this:

***HERE IS THE SERVER SIDE***

```
"<input id='" + cRoadList.getRoadListNumber() + ",start_km' style='' type=\"text\" value='"+ cRoadList.getStartKm() + "' onkeypress='handleRoadListDataUpdate(\""+cRoadList.getStartKm()+"\")'
```

As you see the attrbutes of the input element are generated dynamically but that is not the case so let's simplify it by putting some static data like this:

```
"<input id='myID' style='' type=\"text\" value='100' onkeypress='handleRoadListDataUpdate(\"100\")'
```

The most important part of this HTML input element is the **onkeypress** event which calls the function **handleRoadListDataUpdate**

***HERE IS THE CLIENT PART***

```
function handleRoadListDataUpdate(oValue) // The function accpets the old value of the *input* element
{
   var event = handleRoadListDataUpdate.caller.arguments[0] || window.event ;

   var keyPressed = event.keyCode;
   if(keyPressed == 13)
   {
        var roadListNumber = event.target.id.split(",")[0];
        var inputId        = event.target.id.split(",")[1];
        var nValue         = event.target.value;

        if(nValue != oValue)
        {
               var userAction = confirm("Are you sure you want to change this value?\nPrevious value:   " + oValue + "\nNew value: " + nValue);
               if(userAction == true)
               {   
                    var url = "/GBS/RoadListController";
                    var params = "type=updateRoadList&roadListNumber=" + roadListNumber + "&updateData="+inputId + "&newValue="+ nValue;
                    dhtmlxAjax.post(url,params,function(loader) 
                    {
                            var xmlDoc = loader.xmlDoc.responseXML;

                            var sqlResponse = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("response");
                            var result      = sqlResponse[0].getAttribute("value");

                            if(result == "sql_error")
                            {
                                alert("The operation could not be completed because of an network error!");
                                event.target.value = oValue;
                            }
                            else if(result == "sql_success")
                            {
                                alert("The operation completed successfully!");
                                //Change the parameter oValue of the parent function
                            }  
                    });
               }
               else
               {
                   event.target.value = oValue;
               }
        }     
   }    
}
```

Basically this function is about updating (using ajax) the database with the new value the user enters inside the *input* element and press key *Enter*. **If the parameter oValue is different than the parameter in the input element an ajax request is made so the database can be updated with the new value.**

When the operation completes we have the new value in the *input* element (which is entered by the user) **but the problem is that if he press Enter again the function get executed AGAIN because its parameter oValue is not changed with the new value.**

So my very question is:

How to change the handleRoadListDataUpdate() function's parameter **oValue** to become the same as **nValue** so if the user press Enter by accident the function does not execute the ajax part again?

P.S.

Please no jQuery code! Only pure javaScript!

Comment: Why can you not retrieve the value from `event.target.value` inside `handleRoadListDataUpdate`, instead of enforcing it being passed as a parameter?

Comment: bacause it is going to be changed already with new value entered by the user!

Comment: `event.target.value` will update each time the user changes the value?

Comment: ofcourse. event.target.value is the current value the in the input element just before the user presses Enter

Comment: Ahhaaa of course, sorry. I misunderstood your code. I would recommend you use an additional attribute (`data-*` are good for this), and store the old value in there

Comment: 10x! But as far as i know it is not a part of W3C right?

Comment: Its not technically a valid attribute in < HTML5, *however*, it won't break any browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749276/accessing-data-tag-from-a-non-html5-browser

Comment: Can anyone answer my question?