# How to reuse JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Scenario:**

The MVC web page gets JSON object with lots of data. Upon click of button (there are quiet a number of buttons) I would like to reuse this JSON object and select required JSON Properties (without making a request to server).

It's **not HTML5** so can't use browser local storage. At the moment I'm storing the JSON object on GLOBAL variable and reusing it.

Are there any elegant options available to store and re-use returned JSON object on client side?

Comment: What do you mean by reuse? Between page refreshes as well?

Comment: A global variable is a perfectly acceptable way to do this assuming you don't need to re-use the data after page refreshes. Though using some sort of name-spacing scheme (for all of your code) is better: you'd make the variable "global" within the name-space...

Comment: @JakubKonecki, reuse on one page. Not after refresh as refresh will trigger server request :-)

Comment: @nilpun - than scoped variable or data- attribute is a way to go...

Answer (score 3):

Just cache the data. There is no need to store the JSON in a global variable, I'm sure you'll find a place in your MVC application to scope a local variable. You will have implemented a getter function for the data with a callback. With caching, it'll look like this:

```
var getData = (function(){
    var cache;
    var loading = false;
    var callbacks = [];
    return function(callback) {
        if (typeof cache != "undefined")
            callback(cache);
        else {
            callbacks.push(callback);
            if (!loading) {
                loading = true;
                doSingleHeavyAjaxCall(options, function success(data) {
                    cache = data;
                    for (var cb; cb = callbacks.shift();)
                        cb(cache);
                });
            }
        }
     };
 })();
```

Then use `getData(function callback(data){...})` as often as you want, and it will only trigger one ajax request.

Comment: what's the benefit of this approach as opposed to global variable with proper name spacing

Comment: It has only one (somewhere exposed) interface method, in my example `getData`. Everything it does you elsewise would need to do every time you need the data. What's the benefit of making the cache public?

Answer (score 2):

Another option to Jakubs answer is creating a global variable that you can update and retrieve as you like on the page.

[Global variables get attached to the window object](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable), so just write this in your `<head>` section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.jsonData = {};
</script>
```

Then wherever you're retrieving your data just update that object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax(..., function(data) {
        window.jsonData = data;
    });
</script>
```

Then you can use it wherever you like in your code on that page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.dir(jsonData);
</script>
```

Comment: what's the difference between this approach and global variable.

Comment: @nilpun: This approach is "using a global variable"?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the object in data- attribute of some element - preferably container for the part of your page that represents your data (table, grid):

```
var json = {};

$('#mygrid').data('mydata', json);
```

You can retrieve it later

```
var json = $('#mygrid').data('mydata')
```

jQuery data() method documentation: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @JakubKonecki, isn't Data a HTML 5 attribute

Comment: Data atributes are NOT HTML5 local storage. You could use data- attrbutes in IE4 if you wanted to. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6/5696483#5696483

Comment: Data attributes may officially be html5, but they have worked with older browsers back to at least IE5 days, so... Also, jQuery's `.data()` method can _retrieve_ html5-style data attributes, but it doesn't _store_ data in element attributes (it maintains its own structure internally and keeps track of the element association for you).

Comment: data- attributes rendered in html are HTML5, but $.data() method is not HTML5. $.data() will return you any data- attributes as well, but you can store objects using data() method without HTML5

Comment: @Marko&nilpun I'm afraid you both are wrong. When you use `data` to **set** values, it uses jQuery cache, not attributes.

Comment: @gdoron, when you use .data on an element it gets stored on the dom object via data- attributes. See my link above.

Comment: @Marko. You're wrong, please read the docs for `data`. you can't save objects in attributes, while with `data` you can. it doesn't use the attributes to **SET** values!!!

Comment: @Marko - `.data()` does _not_ store on the DOM object. Your link above doesn't say that it does, and neither does the [jQuery doco for `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/). If you want "proof", think about the fact that `.data()` can store (much) more than just strings...

Comment: You're right, however it does READ the data- attributes from a DOM object. Either way, using .data() does NOT require HTML5 and is UNRELATED to local storage. So YOU CAN use it.