# Using attributes to store values

Tags: javascript, html

I prefer using attributes like lang, dir, id, class and others to store useful data for some javascript functions that reference these objects - I do this to avoid using an array that may have to be updated after every action or change. The problem is that this is a bad practice and I cannot always use the attributes I want, because they're already in use or not available on some tag types.
Is there a better way?

Note that I dont like using multiple values split with a separator as this is slow when dealing with massive amounts of objects.

Answer (score 7):

HTML5 [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) were designed especially for this. From the spec:

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to
>   the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate
>   attributes or elements.

You can use them like this:

```
<div data-random="12345" data-name="James"></div>
```

They are valid on all elements, and every element can have any number of them.

They can be accessed through the [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dataset), which every element should have. If you use jQuery, you can use the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to help resolve issues with [older browsers (and IE)](http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset). If not, you may have to feature-detect the `dataset` property and fall back to [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) where `dataset` is not supported.

Comment: +1 And you can access it with `elem.dataset.random`.

Comment: Thanks thats a really cool overdue idea - im going to start updating my code to conform to this...

Comment: Note that older browsers don’t support `elem.dataset`, but [you can use `getAttribute` to get and set these values instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6).

Comment: Jeez im such a nerd - im so excited about this... thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged both jQuery and HTML5, I think this is precisely what you are looking for, in a elegant and standardized way, without breaking validation.

[HTML5 data-* Attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)