# embedding multiple values in options of <select>

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need to embedd 2 values in each of the options of a drop down list  and then need to be able to pass both of them to a JavaScript function.

```
<select onChange="display(<?=$manufacturers_id?>,<?=$modelID?>,this.value1,this.value2);">
..
..
echo "<option value1=\"".$variantID."\" value2=\"".$month_year."\">".$products_variant." ".$month_year."</option>";
..
..

</select>
```

As you can see this HTML code is generated by PHP, I need these two values fetched from database to passed to a JS function.

I am open to suggestions on better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot add many values in an option.
instead you can use [datasets](http://www.barklund.org/blog/2009/08/28/html-5-datasets/) (html5), like:

```
<select id="myselect">
 <option data-this="foo" data-that="bar">
</select>
```

the javascript to read these values is:

```
var d = document.getElementById("myselect");
var _this = d.options[d.selectedIndex].dataset["this"];
var _that = d.options[d.selectedIndex].dataset["that"];
```

if you dont want to mess with datasets, you can store a JSON object:

```
...
<option value='<?php echo json_encode(array("foo"=>1,"bar"=>2)); ?>'>
...
```

and extract the data like:

```
var d = document.getElementById("myselect");
var option_value = JSON.parse( d.options[d.selectedIndex].value );
```

you choose

**EDITED:**

change this:

```
<select onChange="display(<?=$manufacturers_id?>,<?=$modelID?>,this);">

function display(manufacturers_id,modelid,obj) {
   ... json way
   var option_value = JSON.parse(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);
   // option_value.foo = 1;   

   ... dataset way
   var _this = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].dataset["this"];   
   // _this will have the "foo" value
}
```

Comment: How do I pass this with onChange() in <Select> tag?

Comment: What's the IE support for dataset?  Does the --- [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dataset) mean any version?  No version (!!) ?  (+1 for the json idea, btw)

Comment: No am not using jquery just plain HTML.

Comment: @Adam Rackis check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6) about dataset and the horror in IE6 :) I think the getAttribute() works with ANY attribute, but to works clearly with data-sets the html5 (+doctype) is needed.

Comment: @Adam Rackis, i dont know what the -- value means but i suspect total lack of support? just tested on IE9, total failure, doctyped also.

Comment: @vlzvl - I think you're right.  I just couldn't imagine IE9 not supporting this.  Guess I was wrong. Wow.

Comment: @vlzvl I am getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" on this line: var option_value = JSON.parse(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);

Comment: no - JSON.parse exists in [most](http://caniuse.com/json) browser versions. What value the obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value has? Perhaps some missing brackets will trigger this error.

Comment: I have included JSON JavaScript libraries as well.

Comment: I am getting "{" in alert window.

Comment: GOT IT. I was using double quotes to enclose json object.

Comment: yes, this is common error. JSON uses double quotes to encapsulate data which you must use single quotes to encapsulate the whole json object into html attribute; or one could escape the inner quotes; i prefer the first.

Answer (score 1):

I would render the options like this:

```
<option data-value1="X" data-value2="Y">
```

Then deal with these data- attributes however you want (with jQuery's [`data("value1")`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method, with the native [`getAttribute("data-value1")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute), etc.

Comment: No - data-foo attributes are recognized in any browser -- even ie 6.  Having said that, getAttribute has some limitations in support, so you'd either have to use jQuery, or possibly the dataset collection like vlvl said (which I think has better support)