# JS/jQuery Change Image on Hover of <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I have some HTML shown below, which is generated dynamically in an ASP Classic form.

There can be any amount of groups/tables (Size/Color) with any amount of rows/options.

Each group/table has an img tag, and each row/option has a hidden field with its corresponding image URL.

On the hover of each row, I need to change the src attribute of the image of that group to that row's image URL, using JS or jQuery (something that works in ASP classic).

The HTML can be changed if needed for it to work.

Thank you.

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: 700" colspan="2">
            Color<input id="colorSortOrder" type="hidden" value="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="radioRed" type="radio" name="Color" value="R-" />
            <label for="radioRed">
                Red</label>
            <input type="hidden" value="Image1.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="radioOrange" type="radio" name="Color" value="O-" />
            <label for="radioOrange">
                Orange</label>
            <input type="hidden" value="Image2.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="radioBlue" type="radio" name="Color" value="B-" />
            <label for="radioBlue">
                Blue</label>
            <input type="hidden" value="Image3.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: 700" colspan="2">
            Size<input id="sizeSortOrder" type="hidden" value="2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="radioLarge" type="radio" name="Color" value="LA-" />
            <label for="radioLarge">
                Large</label>
            <input type="hidden" value="Image4.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="radioMedium" type="radio" name="Color" value="ME-" />
            <label for="radioMedium">
                Medium</label>
            <input type="hidden" value="Image5.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="radioSmall" type="radio" name="Color" value="SM-" />
            <label for="radioSmall">
                Small</label>
            <input type="hidden" value="Image6.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...which looks something like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the HTML just a little bit to reduce the JavaScript parsing needed by adding data attributes for the image src like this

http://jsfiddle.net/muDJ9/

and with the use of JavaScript replace you can edit out extensions for the alt tags

EDIT: This also runs the fastest I just ran tests on the others submitted using the console.time() profiler

FINAL: http://jsfiddle.net/FV9cw/

Comment: My table ids and name attributes would be dynamic, so I'm trying to change the jQuery selectors to            *$("table[id^='options'] tr").hover(function () {
                $("[name^='optionVal']").attr({ "src": $(this).data('img'), "alt": $(this).data('img') });
            });* but *$("[name^='optionVal']"* doesn't seem to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Say my html looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/W6j5R/1/ where the id of each image starts with "optionImage".

Comment: how about this EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/L8cpK/
had to move image it was getting annoying

Comment: I need an image per table/group though. Just need to be able to reference the image and I think we're good. And then there's the HTML 5 support thing...

Comment: data attributes work back to IE6 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6

Comment: Alright, and how do we reference the image per table? Possible, right?

Comment: Thanks alot - that helped me get it working with the image where I had it (in the <tr>). *var img = $(this).parent().parent().find("img");*

Comment: Yup no problem glad I could help :)

Comment: BTW, not to go off topic, but none of the links on imstillreallybored.com work (for me)

Comment: Yup I'm working on that I'm actually working on a series of video tutorials.. I just have to edit the .htaccess file the url redirection got messed up some how

Comment: Got the .htaccess sorted if you want to give it a look now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='radio']").hover(function(){
var src = $(this).parent().find("input[type='hidden']").val();
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find("img").attr("src",src);
});
```

Line 1 detects hover.
Line 2 go up to td and looks for the hidden input inside td and takes the value
Line 3 go up three times td > tr > table and looks for img and sets his attribute src with the image.

Comment: Thanks, this works but the selector includes the header row too.

Comment: I was forgot the ] after 'radio'

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as under

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/pZZ82/2/)**

```
$('label[for]').closest('tr').mouseenter(function(){  
    $(this).siblings().find('img').hide();
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', $(this).find('input[type=hidden]').attr('value')).show(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried your code but this seem to only work for the first row of the table.