# How compatible is to store text in data-content and use bootstrap-popover.js?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show some html in popover using http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers. How compatible is to store text in data-content? Will it work in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html in the data attribute, just watch out not to include certain quotation marks. You can use `&quot;` in texts of course but need to use single or double quotes depending on the tag's quotes.

The data attribute should work in most browsers: [Do HTML5 custom data attributes “work” in IE 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6/)

```
<a data-original-title="<em class='tooltip-title'>bar</em>" href="#" rel="tooltip">foo</a>
<a data-original-title='<em class="tooltip-title">bar</em>' href="#" rel="tooltip">foo</a>
```

It works for tooltips, popovers shouldn't be different.