# Classes vs data attribute, auto field initialiser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute, sinemacula

### A Little Background

I have written a method in javascript/jQuery that loops through fields and sets them dependant on what they are i.e. dropdown, autocomplete, text etc...

*The reason for this is that I have specifically styled inputs and textareas, and they must be initialised in javascript once the page has loaded. The method in this class loops through each field on the page and sets the events based on what it is.*

At the moment I am detecting what each field is by giving the field container a class, jQuery reads this class and sets the field accordingly like so:

```
<div id="company-container" class="autocomplete autocomplete-215 form-sprite">
    <input type="text" class="field" name="company" id="company" autocomplete="off" maxlength="80" tabindex="1" />
    <div class="label overflow" id="company-label">Company</div>
    <div class="glow form-sprite" id="company-glow"></div>
    <ul class="subNav"></ul>
</div>
```

The jQuery looks something like this:

```
$(options.fields).each(function(){
    // Set the field events
    SineMacula.setBlur($(this));        
    SineMacula.setFocus($(this));
    SineMacula.toggleLabel($(this));
    // If the field is a drop down then set it
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('dropdown')){
        SineMacula.setDropdown($(this).parent());
    }
    // If the field is a checkbox then set it
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('checkbox')){
        SineMacula.setCheckbox($(this).parent());
    }
    // and so on ...
});
```

***Most of the code above can be ignored, but it should give you an idea of what I am doing...***

### Question

I have recently noticed the HTML5 attribute `data-*`, where `*` can be anything. My question(s) are:

1. Should I be using the HTML5 `data-*` attribute instead of classes?
2. Are there better methods than either the `data-*` attribute or the classes?
3. Although the `data-*` attribute is HTML5, is it compatible with early browsers as long as the correct `DOCTYPE` is defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In this case it probably doesn't matter too much, since you're still using a valid attribute (rather than random custom attributes). If you feel that `data-*` attributes would be more semantic, then go for it.
2. No, that is what the `data-*` attribute is designed for - storing arbitrary data on an element.
3. Yes, it's compatible with all browsers. It will just be ignored by older browsers, but you will always be able to retreive its value with the `getAttribute` method.

Comment: Thank you James, that is what I wanted to know :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are using the classes for styling anyway, you may just as well use them for your jQuery selectors as well. Actually *I believe it will be slightly faster to use classes as selectors*, rather than the `data-*` attributes.
2. If you intend to store some arbitrary data related to the element, the `data-*` attributes are definitely the way to go.
3. Yes, they are backward compatible. With jQuery you can get their values using the `.data()` method. If you intend to read them with plain JavaScript, you need to have a fallback for older browsers where you use `.getAttribute()`. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2413263/678801) elaborate a bit further on it.