# javascript form validation- the function is unable to perform validation

Tags: javascript, validation

This is my form:

[jsFiddle of my FORM](http://jsfiddle.net/JbzPA/)

```
function formValidator(){
var a = document.getElementById('uname');
var b = document.getElementById('m_photo');
var c= document.getElementById('fname');
var d= document.getElementById('lname');
var e= document.getElementById('p_add');
var f= document.getElementById('c_add');
var g= document.getElementById('b_add');
var h= document.getElementById('country');
var i= document.getElementById('state');
var j= document.getElementById('city');
var k= document.getElementById('pcode');
var l= document.getElementById('id_proof');
var m= document.getElementById('quali_proof');
var n= document.getElementById('p_addproof');
var o= document.getElementById('c_addproof');
var p= document.getElementById('resume');
var q= document.getElementById('dob');
var r= document.getElementById('mobile');
var s= document.getElementById('email');
var t= document.getElementById('quali');
var u= document.getElementById('dsgn');
var v= document.getElementById('rep_person');
var w= document.getElementById('join');
var x= document.getElementById('p_hist');
var y= document.getElementById('sh_des');
var z= document.getElementById('app_by');
var A= document.getElementById('accept');

// Check each input in the order that it appears in the form!
if(lengthRestriction(a, 6, 8)){
    if(""==b.value)
        {alert("Please Upload the Member Photo");
            if(isAlphabet(c, "Please enter only Alphabets for First Name")){
                if(isAlphabet(d, "Please enter only Alphabets for Last Name")){
                    if(e==null || e=="")
                        {alert("Please Enter your Permanent Address");
                            if(f==null || f=="")
                                {alert("Please Enter your Current Address");
                                    if(g==null || g=="")
                                        {alert("Please Enter your Branch Address");
                                            if(h==null || h=="")
                                                {alert("Please Enter the Country Name");
                                                    if(i==null || i=="")
                                                        {alert("Please Enter the State Name");
                                                            if(j==null || j=="")
                                                                {alert("Please Enter the City Name");

    //if(isAlphanumeric(addr, "Numbers and Letters Only for Address")){
            if(isNumeric(k, "Please enter a valid 6 digit Pin Code")){
                if(l==null || l=="")
                    {alert("Please Upload the Id-Proof");
                        if(m==null || m=="")
                            {alert("Please Upload the Qualification Proof");
                                if(n==null || n=="")
                                    {alert("Please Upload the Permanent Address Proof");
                                        if(o==null || o=="")
                                            {alert("Please Upload the Current Address Proof");
                                                if(p==null || p=="")
                                                    {alert("Please Upload the Resume");
                                                        if(q==null || q=="")
                                                            {alert("Please Upload the D.O.B Proof");
                                                                if(lengthRestriction(r,10,10)){
                                                                    if(emailValidator(s, "Please enter a valid email address")){
                                                                        if(t==null || t=="")
                                                                            {alert("Please Enter the Qualification Details");
                                                                                if(madeSelection(u, "Please Choose a Designation")){
                                                                                    if(v==null || v=="")
                                                                                        {alert("Please Enter the name of the Reporting Person");
                                                                                            if(w==null || w=="")
                                                                                                {alert("Please Enter the Joining Date");
                                                                                                    if(x==null || x=="")
                                                                                                        {alert("Please Write Something about Past History");
                                                                                                            if(y==null || y=="")
                                                                                                                {alert("Please give some Description about the Member");
                                                                                                                    if(z==null || z=="")
                                                                                                                        {alert("Empty Field: APPOINTED BY");
                                                                                                                            if(madeSelection(A, "Please Accept the terms and conditions")){
                                                                                            return true;
                                                                    }}
                                                                }}
                                                            }}
                                                        }}
                                                    }}
                                                }}
                                            }}
                                        }}
                                    }}
                                }}
                            }}
                        }}
                    }}
                }

return false;


}
 function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
if(elem.value.length == 0){
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus(); // set the focus to this input
    return false;
}
return true;
}

function isNumeric(elem, helperMsg){
var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
if(elem.value.match(numericExpression)){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
}

function isAlphabet(elem, helperMsg){
var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
}

function isAlphanumeric(elem, helperMsg){
var alphaExp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
}

function lengthRestriction(elem, min, max){
var uInput = elem.value;
if(uInput.length >= min && uInput.length <= max){
    return true;
}else{
    alert("Please enter between " +min+ " and " +max+ " characters");
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
}

function madeSelection(elem, helperMsg){
if(elem.value == "Select Designation"){
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}else
    {
    return true;
}
}

function emailValidator(elem, helperMsg){
var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
if(elem.value.match(emailExp)){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
}
```

Here the validation takes place for the first two cases only.  I am unable to figure out the problem. Can any one help?

I am required to validate the current field before the user move to the next field, so all the if statement were nested to follow the specific order.

Also, I wish to redirect the form data to another file. I used `action="abc.html"`(its an eg.).
When the submit button is clicked it directly goes to `abc.html` instead of validating the form data.

Comment: Consider posting your code here and allowing others to help you format it or try creating an example using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Please be more specific with what you mean by "the first two cases."

Comment: @PhilBozak.. the first two cases(or conditions) in the formValidator() function..if you have seen the code

Comment: @user1967018 Consider using something like jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) for posting your code.

Comment: Single letter variable names! Yikes. Do not do that!

Comment: Wow, you've got a lot of nested ifs!

Comment: please also do correct me if i have used wrong logic for the validation.

Comment: @bfavaretto [Arrow Anti-Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. You should really organize that :)

#### Alterante Approach

Since you have this kind of a long form; you can:

- Mark necessary fields as required with a class name.
- Use HTML5 custom `data-` attributes to assign the validation logic and the corresponding error message for *each* field.

For example:

```
<input id="fname" type="text" class="required" data-validation="alphanumeric"
        data-error="Please enter your first name." />

<input id="age" type="text" class="required" data-validation="numeric"
    data-error="Please enter your age." />

<input id="accept" type="checkbox" class="required" data-validation="check" 
    data-error="Please accept the terms of agreement." />
```

Then;

- Get those *"marked-as-required"* fields in a loop.
- Validate them by using the attached logic.
- Either show all the gathered error messages at the end or process and
  break one-by-one (as you do).

For example:

```
function validateForm() {
    // get the .required fields as NodeList
    var requiredElems = document.getElementsByClassName('required') || 
                            document.querySelectorAll('.required');
    // validate fields one-by-one
    for (var i = 0; i < requiredElems.length; i++) {
        var elem = requiredElems[i];
        if (validateField(elem) === false) {
            alert(elem.getAttribute('data-error')); //get the error message from the custom data attribute and alert.
            elem.focus();
            return false; //break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function validateField(elem) {
    var rxp, valid = true,
        // get the validation type from the custom data attribute.
        validationType = elem.getAttribute('data-validation');
    // all validation logic in one place
    switch (validationType) {
        case 'alphanumeric':
            rxp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
            valid = rxp.test(elem.value);
            break;
        case 'numeric':
            rxp = /^[0-9]+$/;
            valid = rxp.test(elem.value);
            break;
        case 'email':
            rxp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
            valid = rxp.test(elem.value);
            break;
        case 'check':
            valid = elem.type == 'checkbox' ? elem.checked : true;
            break;
    }
    
    return valid;
}
```

There is two more benefits to this;

- You can add extra form fields without needing to change your
  javascript. Just insert the element in your HTML with the `.required`
  class, `data-validation` and `data-error` attributes.
- You can add extra validation logic by just adding another `case` in the `validateField()` method.

### HTML5 Form Validation

We could also use proper *HTML5 Form Validation*; such as using the **`required` attribute** instead of a custom `.required` class (to identify required fields in-line). There are lots of other useful features, such as new `input` types (`email`, `number`, `url`, etc), placeholder text, autofocus fields. But unfortunately, these are [**not fully supported**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) by most versions of major browsers yet.

The **'data-'** attribute, on the other hand; is [at least usable, including **IE6**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2413263/112731) (even if it is not really recognized by old browsers). That's why, I think the approach above is more browser-friendly at this time.

For more information on HTML5 Forms, see [this page](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html).

Anyway, this is just to demonstrate how you should structure/organize your flow. There should be much more logical approaches than this one but at least, this should give you an idea.

***Note:** If you consider this approach, don't forget to change your **DOCTYPE** accordingly.*

Comment: THIS IS A VERY GOOD APPROACH SUGGESTED...WILL SHORTLY GET BACK TO YOU TO SHOW MY GRATITUDE....thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(lengthRestriction(a, 6, 8)){
    if(""==b.value)
        {alert("Please Upload the Member Photo");
            if(isAlphabet(c, "Please enter only Alphabets for First Name")){
```

You have some functions (such as lengthRestriction and isAlphabet shown above) that return **true if the field is valid.** However, your inline logic (like with b above) resolves to **false if the field is valid.** I suggest that you write a "not empty" function (or alternatively change the logic in your if statement) so that the if is **true if the field is valid**.

As a suggestion, I acknowledged that I don't know how much control you have over the project; have you considered using a javascript library such as jquery? You might benefit from using code that other people have already written and tested.

Comment: actually i am required to validate the current field before the user move to the next field..so all the if statement were nested to follow the specific order..

Comment: @user1967018 Ok, I will edit my answer.

Comment: it wud be a great help if u solve this problem man... :)

Comment: can u explain with a code snippet(for example on variable b) wat u intend to say???
bdw thanks..