# Can the dataset property be simulated for old browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dataset, simulation

Is there a way to post-define the `dataset` [property of HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) such that it can also be used in older browsers?

Comment: Not without JavaScript *custom properties*, which won't be supported on older browsers either. Consider something like `jQuery.data` instead.

Comment: Possible duplication ? Anyway take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122541/will-html-5-data-attribute-support-in-old-browsers

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Too bad it cannot be simulated. So, if you have a normal audience, you should not use it, it's a shame, because it's a very neat property.