# many javascripts tags inside asp page makes performance low

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net 4.5 (C#) page on VS2013. In this page, I am using a loop to itrate threw some of my objects. for each object(product) I have a textbox (input with type=textbox) which I use jquery on to make it a spinner .

I need this inside the loop for every product since I want each spinner to have it's parameters from the object (min, max, step size, is decimal etc.).

The loop goes something like that:

```
foreach ( Product product in getCart().ItemsList() ) {
  String spinnerId = "spinner_" + product.Code;%>
      <input id="<%:spinnerId %>" name="<%:product.Code%>">
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            setSpinner('<%:spinnerId%>','<%:product.min%>','<%:product.max%>','<%product.step%>');
       </script>
    <%}%>
```

and in the head of the page I have:

```
function setSpinner(id,minVal,maxVal,stepVal){
            j("#"+id).spinner({
                min: minVal,
                max: maxVal,
                step: stepVal,
            });
        }
```

The problem is, that when I have the loop goes over a few times (10-15) the page loads very purley and the "onready" functions are taking a few seconds to perform, which meaning some fields that needs to be hidden are shown for 2 seconds and only than disaperas (this includes ajaxcontroltoolkit controls such as popupextender panel etc.).

To make this simple, the javascript code itself makes no matter. 
If you try something like this:

```
    <%for (int i=0;i<100;i++){%>
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
</script>
<%}%>
```

The same problem occures.

It seemes that even an empty javascript block is making the page take a long time to complete, if youe use it multiple times.

Why are 50\100 empty javascript blocks making the page lag so bad? and what can I do to solve this, considering I have to use the javascript code with each of the my objects data?

Comment: No idea. But it´s ugly and unmaintainable. Do your stuff inside one script block.

Comment: That does not solve any of this. How do you make a spinner with different values for each product (min,max,step) in one block?

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle for what you are trying to do, it's hard reading the question to know.

Comment: I'm trying to call a javascript function on each dynamicley created <input>. there maybe 1 or 50 or 100 of this. the multiple <javascript> blocks that are recreated in each itaration makes the page load take plenty of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the info you need in `data-` HTML attributes, and calling javascript one single time. Something like

```
foreach ( Product product in getCart().ItemsList() ) {
  String spinnerId = "spinner_" + product.Code;%>
      <input id="<%:spinnerId %>" class="spinner" name="<%:product.Code%>" data-min="<%:product.min%>" data-max="<%:product.max%>" data-step="<%:product.step%>">
<%}%>
```

Then iterate on the "spinner" class inputs with jQuery:

```
$("input.spinner").each(function(intput){
  $(this).spinner({
      min: $(this).data('min'),
      max: $(this).data('max'),
      step: $(this).data('step'),
  });
});
```

Comment: is it possible to use the data tag in non-html5 browsers?

Comment: I get the following error: "Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'data' "

Comment: It looks like like you need to rewrap the object in jQuery, I've updated the code in my answer. You probably won't be able to use data- attributes in non-HTML5 browsers without using a workaround. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6

Answer (score 0):

*look at @David's ans first that surely is a better approach*

as cleared by @roland this is ugly.
even if you need to inject js into the web page. inject a js object preferably and array containing all the objects and then inside a single block on `page load` iterate through it and get your work done.

var ps = getCart().ItemsList().Select(p=>new {
 p.Id
/*...All your propertiese...*/
});

now inject ps inside the web page / script tag using any json library like `Newtonsoft.Json`.

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ps);
```