# Are HTML data attributes safe for older browsers e.g. IE 6?

Tags: html, compatibility, custom-data-attribute

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do HTML5 custom data attributes “work” in IE 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6)

Is it safe to use HTML data attributes.

For example if a user uses IE6 as browser, will I still be able to use the attribute and retrieve it using javascript?