# how to identify li item using jquery

Tags: jquery

I've a list

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="?page=4">one</li>    //no 4
  <li><a href="?page=7">two</li>    //no 7
  <li><a href="?page=14">three</li>  //no 14
  <li><a href="?page=72">four</li>   //no 72
  <li><a href="?page=201">five</li>   //no 201
</ul>
```

Now I want to use ajax to load the pages instead of the normal page load. So how do  I detect which link the user clicked using jQuery. Say something like

```
$('id of the element clicked').click(function()({ 
      // Load the page using .ajax() 
});
```

In the jQuery code above, how do I get `id of the element clicked`??

Comment: In your html snippet no one element has `id`. Btw, you can use `$(this).attr('href')`

Comment: not yet.. i can assign that. I thought i could assign like `id="1"` but says id can't start with in integer

Comment: So if i use `$(this).attr('href')`, then 1) will it still reload the page as the `href` value is still there in the markup; 2) How to I load the page using ajax if I get the `?page=id` string?? Do I use something like `.load()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could fetch the id from the `href` attribute of the clicked anchor using regex:

```
$('ul a').click(function() {
    var id = this.href.match(/([0-9]+)$/)[1];
    // Load the page using .ajax()  
});
```

but a better approach IMHO instead of using regex to parse the url is to use HTML5 `data-*` attributes:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="?page=4" data-id="4">one</li>
  <li><a href="?page=7" data-id="7">two</li>
  <li><a href="?page=14" data-id="14">three</li>
  <li><a href="?page=72" data-id="72">four</li>
  <li><a href="?page=201" data-id="201">five</li>
</ul>
```

and then:

```
$('ul a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    // Load the page using .ajax()  
});
```

Some other answers are suggesting using the `id` attribute but adding `id="4"` to the anchor would be invalid markup as according to the specification the id of a DOM element cannot start with a number.

Comment: Are there any compatibility issues with `data-id` with older browsers??

Comment: @ptamzz, please define *older browser*. I would recommend you [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). You may take a look at the [following question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249261/html-5-browser-compatibility-chart-html-5-in-old-browsers) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Don't need an id, use `$(this)` ;)

For example :

```
$("li").click(function(){
  $(this).//do ajax stuff
});
```

And if you want to get the href of the clicked element : `$(this).children('a').attr('href')`

Comment: This is essentially correct; however, the li needs to be in quotes: $("li").click(...

Answer (score 0):

you can get the `id` attribute of the `<a>` like this:

```
$("ul>li>a").click(function(){
   // the id of the anchor
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
   // the id of the li
   alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
   // link's page id
   alert($(this).attr('href').match(/page=(\d+)$/));
});
```

Comment: he wanted the id of the list item, not the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

to get the id first assign ids to your li and then try this one...

```
$('li').click(function(){

      $(this).attr('id') ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but could you not have just done this:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        $('a', this).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#somediv').load(href);
        });
    });
});
```